# Appending a list to a separate list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-3.4

So far my code takes in inputs from the user, all of which is then appended to a list.

```
list1.append(input1)

list1.append(input2)

etc
```

Then I append this list into a new list

```
list2.append(list1)
```

All of this works fine but when I try to clear list1, so the user can input data for a new list1, the list is also cleared from list2

```
del list1 [:]
```

So only the most recent list1 is shown when list2 is printed. Is there a better data structure to use? Or will this work if there was a different syntax to the code?

The ideal structure I would like this list to have is:

```
list2 = [[x, y, z],[a,b,c],[g,h,i]]
```

(There are far more items in my actual code)

Though at the moment its more like:

```
list2 = [[], [], [g,h,i]]
```

Later on I would like to be able to identify and print all the lists if their second item is "y". So in the example above, [x,y,z] will be returned. Is this possible using a 2D list?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options ... You can either put a *copy* of `list1` into `list2`:

```
list2.append(list1.copy())  # `list1[:]` for older python versions
```

Or, rather than clearing `list1`, you can just make a new list:

```
list2.append(list1)
list1 = []  # Rather than `del list1[:]`
```

This latter version is going to be more common (and better performing) and is the solution that I'd usually recommend.

Comment: the "two option" part is the only way to answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because lists pass by reference, so when you call `list2.append(list1)`, you are really just appending a reference to `list1` onto `list2`.

So, if you modify `list1` at all, the modifications can be seen in `list2`:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2]
>>> list2 = [list1]
>>> list1
[1, 2]
>>> list2
[[1, 2]]
>>> list1.append(3)
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list2
[[1, 2, 3]] # list1's changes can be seen here
```

To get around this, you can either append a copy of `list1` onto `list2`:

`list2.append(list1[:])`

or more preferably, just "reset" the variable `list1`. Instead of `del list1[:]`, which modifies the list in-place:

`list1 = []`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your getting this behavior is because your appending a *reference* to `list1` instead of a copy. This is because of the way Python list work. Unless you explicitly tell python to *copy* the contents of a list, a *refernece* to the list will be appended instead. This means that when saying `del list1[:]` you also affect the reference to `list1` in `list2`

This can be solved by explicitly telling Python to copy the contents of your list, instead of simply copying a reference to the same list.

```
list2.append(list1.copy()) # or list[:]
```

For more complex structures, [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) should be used instead:

```
>>> import copy
...
>>> list2.append(copy.deepcopy(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2.append(list1)
```

list2 just append list1 reference. You need append copy of list1.

```
import copy
list2.append(copy.copy(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `list2.append(list1)`, you should use:

```
list2.append(list1[:])  # Or list1.copy()
```

Now, a copy of `list1` is appended to `list2` instead of `list1` itself.

**Output:**

*With `list2.append(list1)`:*

```
>>> list2 = []
>>> 
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> del list1[:]
>>> 
>>> list1 = [1, 5, 5]
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> 
>>> list2
[[], [1, 5, 5]]
```

*With `list2.append(list1[:])`:*

```
>>> list2 = []
>>>
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2.append(list1[:])
>>> del list1[:]
>>>
>>> list1 = [1, 5, 5]
>>> list2.append(list1[:])
>>>
>>> list2
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 5]]
```